# Qualified dependent name lookup with injected-class-name of base class

Tags: c++, c++20

The most recent versions of clang, gcc and msvc (/permissive-) all reject the following code:

```
struct B {
    void func() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Base : B {
    void func() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
    void func() {
        this->Base::func(); // (*) fails here, even though this->B::func(); works
    }
};

// for msvc, use /permissive- and the following instantiation for the error to trigger:
int main() {
    Derived<void> d;
    d.func();
}
```

My understanding of the current standard is that (*) is considered a *member of an unknown specialization*, according to https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#dep.type-6.3 , and therefore, name resolution would be delayed to template instantiation, but given that (*) is also a qualified function call, the lookup should also be performed in the base class even though it's dependent, and it should then find the injected-class-name: `Base`.

Is this code really invalid or is it a compiler bug? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In the class member access expression `this->Base::func`, the id-expression is `Base::func`. Inside this expression, `Base` is not a member of an unknown specialization.

If you want this to be a member of an unknown specialization you must qualify it with the injected class name:

```
template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
    void func() {
        this->Derived::Base::func(); // compiles: Base is now a member of an unknown specialization
    }
};
```

Comment: According to [temp.dep.type] §5.3 and §6.3 - it mentions that, if the id-expression is not found in the current instantiation, nor in a non-dependent base class - and there is a dependent base class, then this expression is already considered a member of unknown specialization. I cannot find any mention of the nested-name-specifier of the id-expression of the class member access itself, as you imply in your answer. Can you provide a reference for the rule you seem to imply, or why §5.3 and §6.3 does no apply here?

Comment: @obelloc The problem is that the id-expression is itself decomposed in a nested-name-specifier:: id-expression. The rule you site only apply for the whole id-expression `Base::func`, not for the element of the subexpression.

Comment: Exactly, the rule applies for the whole id-expression, and that's why the rule implies it's then a member of unknown specialization, I can't find an exception for the rule. Moreover, if you use this->B::func(), the same rule applies, B::func refers to a member of unknown specialization, but then it actually works.

Comment: @obelloc `B` is the name of a structure. It is found by unqualified name lookup. It is not found as a member of an unknown specialization. [exemple](https://godbolt.org/z/KN3HEU).  `Base` is a template name, to be usable as a nested-name-specifier, it must be a template id: `Base <T>`. `Derived::Base` Is a member of an unknown specialization in the template definition. And when instantiated it resolves to the injected class name of Base<void>.

Comment: Oliv, I don't know where you are taking these rules from. According to the paragraphs I quoted, it will perform a name lookup only in the current instance or in non-dependent base classes, because the "type of the object expression is the current instantiation" (this pointer). Your example is broken for another reason, Base should derive from N::B. After correcting your example: https://godbolt.org/z/ihTMpJ . At least clang compiles, and there is no struct B reachable, even outside Derived<T>, which should not matter nonetheless according to the rules I quoted.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but to save your time, if you are not going to give a precise explanation on what should happen, by the standard, including the rules I mentioned and why they don't apply, and quoting the other pertinent rules if applicable, I don't think it's worth replying. I am not particularly interested on examples on how each compiler behaves currently, but rather on how they should behave, by the standard.

Comment: @obelloc I don't know why you decided to read [dep.type]/6.3.1 as "the type of the object expression is the current instantiation, the current instantiation has at least one dependent base class, and the id-expression is ill-formed". This is not what is written but this is how you understand it. So indeed I can not help you.

Comment: @obelloc Only the member lookup fail, the member is named by the last component of the qualified-id, this is how I read it. This how compiler does.

Comment: @obelloc The relation you have with the standard express some kind of fundamentalism inside the community. The standard is not a specification that is written by the boss and compiler implementers are the sub-contractors. The santandard is developped with compiler coder and many actors. Often even if the standard does not look clear it is clear for compiler implementer because they know the intent which is not written in the standard (which is a dubious mistake). So if all compilers expose a common behavior, that  common behavior is the right, on your lecture is wrong.

Comment: @obelloc: Try to be nice; the standard isn’t trivial to interpret at the best of times, and name lookup is [something of a disaster](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r4.html).  The relevant rule here is [basic.lookup.classref]/4: if `Base` isn’t found “in the class of the object expression”, it’s subject to unqualified lookup.  How that interacts with the dependent case isn’t specified anywhere; [temp.dep.type] isn’t much help because you can’t do name lookup on entire *id-expression*s at once.